# Remove content between two span using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a title="Go to Innomations." href="" class="home">Home</a></span>
    >>
    <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="turnoffmain">
    <a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to Products." href="">Products</a></span> 
</div>
```

I want to remove the content `>>` between two span.

How can i do this ?

I tried like this

```
$("a").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("title") == "Go to Products."){
      $(this).closest('span').addClass('turnoffmain');
    }
```

i.e., iterated towards a href and identified the `"Go to Products."` and added a class `turnoffmain` which will hide the second span.

But how can i remove the `>>` between those two spans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with the help of `contents()` and `each()`

```js
$('.breadcrumbs').contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3)
    this.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a title="Go to Innomations." href="" class="home">Home</a></span>
  >>
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="turnoffmain">
    <a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to Products." href="">Products</a></span> 
</div>
```

Or more specific removing element between `span` tag

```js
$('.breadcrumbs').contents().each(function() {
  console.log(this.nextSibling.nodeName == 'SPAN');

  if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nextSibling && this.prevSibling && this.nextSibling.nodeName == 'SPAN' && this.prevSibling.nodeName == 'SPAN')
    this.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a title="Go to Innomations." href="" class="home">Home</a></span>
  >>
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="turnoffmain">
    <a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to Products." href="">Products</a></span> 
</div>
```

Or as you said removing content if it is above the class `turnoffmain`

```js
$('.breadcrumbs').contents().each(function() {
  console.log(this.nextSibling.nodeName == 'SPAN');

  if (this.nodeType == 3 && $(this.nextSibling).is('.turnoffmain'))
    this.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
    <a title="Go to Innomations." href="" class="home">Home</a></span>
  >>
  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="turnoffmain">
    <a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to Products." href="">Products</a></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. If i have more than 2 span, its deleting all the `>>` symbols, Is that possible to remove the `>>` only above the span that have the class name `turnoffmain` ?

Comment: Thanks, i will try and let you know in few seconds

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = '<div class="breadcrumbs"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">    <a title="Go to Innomations." href="" class="home">Home</a></span> >> <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="turnoffmain"><a rel="v:url" property="v:title" title="Go to Products."href="">Products</a></span> </div>';

var str = a;
str = str.replace(">>", "");
alert(a)
```

Basic example;